# Is there any way I can send a variable as an argument to the constructor of a controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, controller

I am new to CodeIgniter. I was just thinking, is there any way I can send any variable to the constructor of a controller, the same way I can do in Java when I create an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send variables to controller function through URL.

For example, if your URL is www.domain.com/index.php/reports/userdata/35
then your controller function in file controllers/reports.php would look like:

```
function userdata($userId) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: I know how to do that. I just wanted to send this variable to the constructor of the controller. I there anyway I can do that?

Comment: ok... one workaround is by accessing URL segments inside constructor.
    $this->uri->segment(3);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want do this and where you intend to get the variable you are sending from but this does work in this case:

```
function __construct($f=null) {
    parent::__construct();

    if($f){
       return $f; //Here use the variable for whatsoever you want.
    }
}

function testvariable($id) { //Using $id, you could still get the value from url

    $myVariable = 3; //Or you could just hard code the value

    if($id){
    $myVariable = $id;
}

    echo $this->__construct($myVariable);
    exit;
}
```

When you run `http://localhost/controller/testvariable/54`

You'd get the result 54

When you run `http://localhost/controller/testvariable`

You'd get the result 3

Outside these, the other option would be to define the variable in the construct.